# Building a minimal Sparkling Water application

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

I am new to the sparkling water. I now how to run my program from sparkling-shell. However, I am not sure how to build a standalone application that I can give as an input to spark submit. What are the jars that I need to include to build my application?

Comment: Is there a new version of sparkling droplet that uses Spark 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [sparkling-water examples](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/tree/master/examples) e.g. [ProstateDemo.scala](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/h2o/ProstateDemo.scala) to how to write standalone sparkling-water app (creating h2o context, etc.).

Basically you [need to add](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cai.h2o%7Csparkling-water-core_2.11%7C2.0.4%7Cjar) `sparkling-water-core` to your sbt/maven/gradle dependency, compile your jar. You have 2 options:

1. Build an assembly jar with sparkling-water-core in it. Here's an example i'm using for sbt:

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" %% "sparkling-water-core" % "2.0.4" excludeAll(
   ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.spark"),
   ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),
   ExclusionRule(organization = "com.google.guava"),
   ExclusionRule(organization = "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit"),
   ExclusionRule(organization = "com.esotericsoftware.kryo"))
   ```
2. Compile your jar and use `--jars` or `--packages` argument to spark submit:

`spark-submit --packages ai.h2o:sparkling-water-core_2.11:2.0.4 your_jar.jar`

Comment: It works!! Thanks so much. I also had to include libraryDependencies += "ai.h2o" %% "sparkling-water-repl" % "2.0.4" to run the app.

Comment: Great. I've disabled repl in my project with `spark.ext.h2o.repl.enabled=false` in h2oConf

Answer (score 0):

FYI: there is also Sparkling Water Droplet which contains `stb` definition:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/blob/master/sparkling-water-droplet/build.sbt